# Disabling edit property in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Anyone knows how to disable the edit property in excel cells?

What I want is, if the user directly click (not double click) the cell, it will prompt a message that says:

> You are not allowed to edit the content!

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C21:D" & ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "You are not allowed to edit the content!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    End If
End Sub
```

But it returns an error saying :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about if you do ...

```
Option Explicit
Public OriginalCell As Range
Public ProtectedCell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Set OriginalCell = [A5]

    If Not Intersect(Target, [A1:B1]) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set ProtectedCell = Target
        MsgBox "Access Denied", vbExclamation, "Access Status"
        OriginalCell.Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Else
        Set OriginalCell = Target
    End If
End Sub
```

*Click, Double click or Select sheet Prompt MsgBox*

**Edit**

```
Option Explicit
Public OriginalCell As Range
Public ProtectedCell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set OriginalCell = Range("C22")

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C21:D" & ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set ProtectedCell = Target
        MsgBox "Access Denied", vbExclamation, "Access Status"
        OriginalCell.Select
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Else
        Set OriginalCell = Target
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It returns an error to this line : OriginalCell.Select saying `Object Required`. Thanks!

Comment: eh! what about if you save your Excel file as `.xls`  ?

Comment: Uh oh! If I will do that, the other functionalities will not work. That's the scenario that will kill me ..

Comment: what about if you set `Set OriginalCell = [A5]` returning selection to cell that is not protected? see updated answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105659/discussion-between-ramedju-and-om3r).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've found great ideas from your answers!

Answer (score 2):

I have finally done it this way:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C1:D" & ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)) Is Nothing Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ProtectedCell = Target
    MsgBox "Access Denied", vbExclamation, "Access Status"
    Cells(lastRow, 3).Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If
```

Thanks all for the help and ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA for this, that's a functionality built into Excel already.

Simply protect the sheet (with or without a password); all "locked" cells will no longer be editable. Change which cells are locked using cell properties (Ctrl+1), in the "Protection" tab.

You can programmatically toggle worksheet protection using the `Worksheet.Protect` / `Worksheet.Unprotect` methods.

Comment: Is there's any other way I can do this without using the protect/unprotect method? Thanks!

Comment: Why fight Excel and reinvent the wheel? There's an existing mechanism that does exactly what you're after already!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the sub for SelectionChange

Try `SelectionChange` instead of `BeforeDoubleClick` in your snippet

Comment: I've edited my question for more information. Thanks!